# My Proof of the Existence of Topology, is this correct reasoning? Also helps on Uniqueness

Tags: general-topology

The question is

> If $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ is a topological space, and $f: X \to Y$ is a bijection. Show that there exists an unique $\mathcal{T}_Y$ such that $f : (X, \mathcal{T}_X) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y) $ is homeomorphism.

My Proof of existence:

First I prove a lemma : if  $f: X \to Y$ is bijective,

(a) $U \subset X \implies (f^{-1})^{-1} (U) = f(U)$ (first is inverse function, the second is pre-image)

my proof:

Let $g = f^{-1} : Y \to X$

by definition of pre-image:

$f^{-1} (U) :=$ {$x \in X : f(x) \in U \subset Y$}

we have
$z \in g^{-1}(U) \implies g(z) \in U \implies f^{-1} (z) \in U \implies z \in f(U) $.  Hence, $(f^{-1})^{-1} (U) \subset f(U)$

Conversely, $z \in f(U) \implies f^{-1}(z) \in U \implies g(z) \in U \implies z \in g^{-1} (U)$. We have $ f(U) \subset (f^{-1})^{-1} (U)$. We have (a) equality

(b) If $V \subset Y$, then $f(f^{-1}(V)) = V$

my proof: since $f^{-1}(V)$ := {$x \in X, f(x) \in V \subset Y$}.

$\forall x \in f^{-1}(V), f(x) \in V$. So $f(x) \in f(f^{-1} (V)) \subset V$

Conversely, $\forall x \in V, \exists z : f(z) = x \in V \subset Y$. we have $z \in f^{-1} (V)$ and $x = f(z) \in f(f^{-1}(V))$ We have $v \subset f(f^{-1}(V))$. Proved the (b) equality.

Now, we construct a topology:

Let $V=f(U)$ for some open $U$ in $X$. Then $V = (f^{-1})^{-1}(U)$  Let $\mathcal{T}_Y$ be collection of all such $V$

Then I prove $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is topology ?

Is my thoughts correct? and is my proof of lemma correct? how do i show this is a unique topology? I find this proof a bit long and complicated, any easier way of solving it? I also kind having trouble of showing $f$ is homeomorphism as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to prove those lemmas, but they do look correct. You defined $\mathcal{T}_Y$ as, I think, $V\subset Y$ is in $\mathcal{T}_Y$ iff $V=f(U)$ for some $U$ in $\mathcal{T}_X$ which is correct.

**$\mathcal{T}_Y$ defines a topology**: This follows from the fact that $\bigcup_{i\in I}f(U_i)=f \left( \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i \right)$ and same for intersections since $f$ is injective.

**$f^{-1}$ is continuous which means $f$ is a homeomorphism**: For every $U$ open in $X$, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=f(U)$ is open in $Y$ by construction.

**Uniqueness**: This follows from continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ because $U$ is open in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: one thing: $z \in f(U) \implies f^{-1}(z) \in U \implies g(z) \in U$, I'm bit confused, $f^{-1}$ here is pre-image, and $ g$ is inverse of $f$, can this guarantee the second implication?

Comment: If you are regarding $f^{-1}$ as the pre-image, then it is a set so that $f^{-1}(z)=\{g(z)\}$ and $f^{-1}(z)\subset U$ (actually, it should be written $f^{-1}(\{z\})$). Since $f$ is bijective, you can neglect the whole pre-image concept and talk about $f^{-1}$ as a function. It'll be far less ambiguous and easier to follow. In fact, most people regard $f^{-1}$ as a pre-image only if it is not a function. In my answer, $f^{-1}$ is only referred to as a function.

Comment: @another question, if a linear map(implies its continuity) is bijective, is this guarantee this map is homeomorphism?

Comment: @Hobbit6094 I don't know what you mean by linear map. For a map $\varphi$ to be a homeomorphism, $\varphi$ needs to be a continuous bijection and $\varphi^{-1}$ also needs to be continuous.

Comment: linear transformation on real vector space, and this linear transformation is bijective, which means isomorphism. If I introduce an arbitrary topology, then this transformation is also homeomorphism. Since linear transformation, it's inverse is also a linear transformation.

Comment: For linear transformations, the same applies, and the continuity conditions depend on the respective topologies. Applying your theorem, if $\varphi :V \rightarrow M$ is a continuous linear map of topological vector spaces with topologies $\mathcal{T}_V$ and $\mathcal{T}_M$, then $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism iff $\mathcal{T}_M$ agrees with the unique topology described in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify the proof for your lemmas, but they seem correct.

We want to show the unique topology is $ \mathcal{T}_y= f( \mathcal{T}_x )= \{ f(V) | V \in \mathcal{T}_x \}  $

Now consider a topology $\mathcal{T}_y'$ that also makes f a homeomorphism. Firstly we show $\mathcal{T}_y \subset \mathcal{T}_y'$. If $ \exists U \in \mathcal{T}_y $ such that $ U \not \in \mathcal{T}_y'$ then consider $f^{-1}(U)$ which is open in $\mathcal{T}_x$ and we see that $ \mathcal{T}_y' $ is not a homeomorphism so $\mathcal{T}_y \subset \mathcal{T}_y'$.

If $ \exists U \in \mathcal{T}_y' $ such that $ U \not \in \mathcal{T}_y$ then consider $f^{-1}(U)$ which is not open in $\mathcal{T}_x$ and we see that $ \mathcal{T}_y' $ is not a homeomorphism so $\mathcal{T}_y' \subset \mathcal{T}_y$.

So therefore $\mathcal{T}_y=\mathcal{T}_y'$ and we have shown the topology is unique.